# Why 1-0.9 is not 0.1?

Tags: python

Why when I'm doing this simple math subtraction I get this answer ?

```
In[10]: 1-0.9
Out[10]: 0.09999999999999998
```

someone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Use `round(1-0.9, n)` where it rounds the result to n decimal places

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the reference, this is very helpful.

Comment: This is only a fix because this operation reduces the number of bits in the significand. In operations where the size of the significand does not change this will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with floating point precision. Usually people round when floats are displayed so the precision limitation is not shown.